# Recursive query over hierarchy and peers

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I have some data that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE relations (
  group_member_id int not null,
  group_boss_id int not null);

INSERT INTO relations (group_member_id, group_boss_id)
VALUES (19, 21), (21, 21), (19, 20), (20, 20), (21, 22), (22, 22);
```

The basic idea is that a group member might be in various different groups with various different bosses (e.g. 19 is in two groups, with bosses 21 and 20 respectively). A group member might be his own boss (e.g. 20 is the boss of 20).

**Implicitly**, a group member is in the same group with another group member if those members share the same boss. So 19 and 21 are in the same group because they share 21 as a boss, 19 and 20 are in the same group because they share 20 as a boss, and 21 and 22 are in the same group because they share 22 as a boss.

For each group member, I want to find the **largest** boss ID, not only of the boss IDs explicitly tied to that group member, but of all boss IDs tied to that member's other implicit group members, and their group members, and so on. The final output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
group_member_id | largest_boss_id
        19           22
        20           22
        21           22
        22           22
```

I've tried coding this non-recursively without much luck: the main problem I'm having is following the relationship from 20 to 21, then from 21 to 22, and gathering peer group members at each step.

Comment: Since you are looking for the "largest boss ID", do the ideas have some meaning? In particular, is `group_member_id <= group_boss_id` always true? Also, since you are working with a temp table, can you post the source of this information - there may be a more efficient solution on that structure.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, group_member_id will always be <= group_boss_id. The actual problem I'm chewing on is a data deduplication problem: each "group_member_id" is the ID of some row, and the "largest_boss_id" is the ID of a tentative deduplicated version of that row. I'm really trying to determine that rows 19, 20, 21, and 22 are all really copies of the same row and thus should all get mapped to row 22 by virtue of them all being linked together in the same chain to "boss" 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been a rather easy query, if it had not been for the peer membership issue (i.e. member #20 having uber boss #22 by virtue of having member #19 as peer).

The easy part is the recursive query `membership` which builds all *direct* relationships, including through multiple levels of hierarchy. However, member #20 will have itself as uber boss because peer relationships are not considered.

The uber bosses of all the peers are added in the `UNION` with rows coming out of the `membership` CTE. For each member find other members of which this member is the boss (the sub-`SELECT` in the `WHERE` filter), then find the uber boss of all of those members and make pairs with the current member. (Yeah, not easy to explain...). Since the query uses a simple `UNION` (instead of `UNION ALL`), all duplicates are removed.

Finally, in the main query, select the pairs of (member, uber boss).

```
SELECT group_member_id, max(group_boss_id) AS uber_boss
FROM (
  -- Recursive query identifies all direct relationships
  WITH RECURSIVE membership AS (
    SELECT group_member_id, group_boss_id FROM relations
    UNION
    SELECT m.group_member_id, r.group_boss_id
    FROM membership m
    JOIN relations r ON r.group_member_id = m.group_boss_id
  )
  SELECT * FROM membership

  UNION

  -- Now need to find all uber bosses of peers
  SELECT m.group_member_id, uber_boss
  FROM membership m,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT group_member_id, max(group_boss_id) AS uber_boss
    FROM membership
    WHERE group_member_id IN (
      -- The below selects the peers
      SELECT group_member_id FROM membership WHERE group_boss_id = m.group_member_id)
    GROUP BY 1
    ) chief

) qry
GROUP BY group_member_id
ORDER BY group_member_id;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/62f69/77)

Comment: This is **awesome** thank you so much (and for the editing help as well). I'm still digesting the code and explanation, but it seems to give me exactly what I'm after.